# How can I get an installation of k3s working with KubeApps?

Tags: k3s, kubeapps

How can I get an install of KubeApps running on K3s? What are the minimal required steps?

Comment: What details or clarity is needed here, it's a self answered question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Installing k3s and kubeapps

1. Install k3s, ([official instructions](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/))

   ```sh
   curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
   ```
2. Add `KUBECONFIG` for user. ([Devops.StackExchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/16043/18965))

   ```sh
   export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
   mkdir ~/.kube 2> /dev/null
   sudo k3s kubectl config view --raw > "$KUBECONFIG"
   chmod 600 "$KUBECONFIG"
   ```
3. Install Helm, ([offical instructions](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/))

   ```sh
   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash
   ```
4. Setup Kubeapps, ([official instructions](https://kubeapps.dev/))

   1. Install Kubeapps

      ```sh
      helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
      helm repo update
      helm install -n kubeapps --create-namespace kubeapps bitnami/kubeapps
      ```
   2. Configure Kubeapps

      ```sh
      kubectl create --namespace default serviceaccount kubeapps-operator

      kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubeapps-operator --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:kubeapps-operator

      cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      metadata:
        name: kubeapps-operator-token
        namespace: default
        annotations:
          kubernetes.io/service-account.name: kubeapps-operator
      type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
      EOF

      kubectl get --namespace default secret kubeapps-operator-token -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' -o go-template='{{.data.token | base64decode}}' && echo
      ```
   3. Play (note we have a slight modification with [`--address 0.0.0.0`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/16106/18965))

      ```sh
      kubectl port-forward -n kubeapps --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kubeapps 8080:80
      ```

## Removal

```sh
sudo k3s-uninstall.sh

# Remove helm, and caches
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/helm ~/.cache/helm /root/.cache/helm

# Remove logs
sudo rm -rf /var/log/pods/

# Your own cluster config/keys/kubeconfig
sudo rm -rf ~/.kube
```